# How to report Jacoco Groovy code coverage to Sonar using new Gradle SonarQube plugin?

Tags: gradle, groovy, sonarqube, jacoco, sonarqube-scan

I've a multi-module Groovy project using Gradle. I applied jacoco, sonarqube plugins.

I was able to

1. Find build/jacoco/test.exec. Jenkins was able to render it right.
2. Browse jacocoHtml with all code coverage details
3. Find Unit tests results and Source code on SonarQube

But `Code Coverage` wasn't getting reported to SonarQube.

Here's my build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id "org.sonarqube" version "2.0.1"
}

allprojects {
    group = 'my'
    version = '1.0-SNAPSHOT'
}

subprojects {
    apply plugin: 'groovy'
    apply plugin: "jacoco"

    dependencies {
        compile group: 'org.codehaus.groovy', name: 'groovy-all', version: '2.4.1'
        testCompile group: 'org.spockframework', name: 'spock-core', version: '1.0-groovy-2.4'
        testCompile group: 'org.assertj', name: 'assertj-core', version: '2.4.1'
    }
}
```

I observed following log statements during a build.

```
No binary directories defined for project core.
Project coverage is set to 0% since there is no directories with classes.
```

I then tried adding following to subprojects or allprojects and still the coverage wasn't being reported to SonarQube.

```
sonarqube {
    properties {
        property "sonar.groovy.jacoco.reportPath", "${project.buildDir}/jacoco/test.exec"
        property "sonar.jacoco.reportPath", "${project.buildDir}/jacoco/test.exec"
        property "sonar.binaries", "${project.buildDir}/classes"
        property "sonar.groovy.binaries", "${project.buildDir}/classes"
    }
}
```

How can I enable reporting Jacoco Groovy code coverage to SonarQube?

Comment: I think your config seems okay. Although we used this for binaries: "$project.buildDir.name/classes". Maybe you could add a longer snippet from your log where it specifically list your module and the path where it looks for the coverage file. Update: you want to apply the sonarqube plugin to the root, otherwise it might think they are separate projects actually.

Comment: Now I have a similar issue where for one project this works, but not for the other. Have you tried applying the configuration on the root directly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may have seen my comments as I battled with the same problem.

I've found the groovy plugin's site, where an issue is reported as follows:

> sonar.groovy.binaries is resolved only once for the root project. In a
>   multi-module project where the property is not defined on the root
>   module but only on leaf modules this cause missing coverage
>   information.

https://github.com/SonarQubeCommunity/sonar-groovy/issues/52

So even if it's set for your module:

":myspecialsubmodule.sonar.groovy.binaries" -> "/home/user/Projects/root-project/myspecialsubmodule/build/classes/main"

It won't work, until it's set for the root.

After setting the config specifically on the root (for now, until the issue is fixed) made it work for me.

```
property "sonar.groovy.binaries", "${project.buildDir.name}${File.separator}classes"
```

I will keep track of the github issue to know when I can remove this workaround.

Comment: Let me try that. Thanks very much. Will post an update.

Comment: It worked. Thanks. Please edit the relevant part in your answer to `"${project.buildDir.name}${File.separator}classes"`